# jQuery GMap hide Labels

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I have been looking for a solution for this, but couldn't find any.

I have a map created with [jQuery GMap](http://gmap.nurtext.de/) 
What i want to do is to remove Country Labels from the map. Or even remove all labels.
How to do that?

Code:

```
function prepareData(json){
    $("#tweets_map").gMap({ 
        maptype: G_NORMAL_MAP,
        controls: ["GSmallZoomControl"],
        markers: json,
        zoom: 5
    });
}
```

Comment: It is facilitated in google api3, I had tested and done same thing you need with simple javascript. I am not sure if jQuery Gmap is using the same api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

based on your [[image]google-maps](/questions/tagged/google-maps) tag, its actually very simple:

create a StyledMapType and pass the styles you want (`visibility: "off"` to `labels`).

see a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/RASG/vA4eQ/

click "hide/show labels" to toggle.